# Save Dictionary Key inside Value class

Tags: c#, dictionary

Imagine code like the following:

```
Dictionary<string, MyClass> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, MyClass>() {
    { "Name 1", new MyClass("Name 1", "Second Value 1") },
    { "Name 2", new MyClass("Name 2", "Second Value 2") },
    { "Name 3", new MyClass("Name 3", "Second Value 3") }
}
```

I need `MyClass` to store the key (eg "Name 1") as a field. I'd also like the flexibility of the `Dictionary` for what I'm doing (taking advantage of accessing an item by a key).

I can't figure out a way of accomplishing what I want without specifying the key twice like in the code above.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Going from the assumption that MyClass has the Properties string1 and string2. Why don't you use Linq? ListOfMyClass.Where(x => x.string1 == "Name 1").ToList() ?

Comment: @DieterB A Dictionary has O(1) retrieval time complexity, whereas `Where` iterates over ***all*** elements, hence O(n) time complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create all your `MyClass` instances in an array and then convert said array into a dictionary using [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx):

```
Dictionary<string, MyClass> dictionary = new MyClass[]
{
    new MyClass("Name 1", "Second Value 1"),
    new MyClass("Name 2", "Second Value 2"),
    new MyClass("Name 3", "Second Value 3")
}.ToDictionary(c => c.NameProperty, c => c);
```

Note that `NameProperty` should be the property that holds the dictionary's key (The one that holds these `"Name X"` values)

Answer (score 1):

What you want is actually a bidirectional mapping between the objects and their names, therefore under the hood the keys have to be stored twice (in both mapping directions), but you can hide the behavior with:

1) extension methods

```
public static void Add(this Dictionary<string, MyClass> dictionary, Myclass obj){
    dictionary.Add(obj.name, obj);
}
```

2) Or by deriving a class from Dictionary and write new functions to add and modify stored objects (like the extension  method above).

```
class A : Dictionary<String, MyClass>
{
    public void Add(MyClass m)
    {
        this.Add(m.Name,m);
    }
}
```

*This case it will also work, which is what you really want, I think:

```
A a = new A() {new MyClass("name", "second value") };
```

3) Writing implicit conversion operators for myClass to KeyValuePair and vice-versa. In this case you can use MyClass instances like KeyValuePairs with your dictionary (except in initializer list!).

```
class MyClass
{

// ...other members 

public static implicit operator KeyValuePair<string,MyClass>(MyClass obj)
{
    return new KeyValuePair<string,MyClass>(obj.Name,obj);
}

public static implicit operator MyClass(KeyValuePair<string,MyClass> kvp)
{
    return kvp.Value;
}
```

}

Feel free to use and combine the methods above.

Answer (score 0):

Another LINQ-esque solution using ToDictionary (avoiding the need for a field):

```
var dictionary = new[] { "Name 1", "Name 2", "Name 3" }
    .ToDictionary(k => k, v => new MyClass(v, "Second Value"));
```

But this might not be appropriate given you requirements on "Second Value".

**EDIT:**

Alternative solution if you have naming criteria for the second parameter:

```
var dictionary = Enumerable.Range(1, 3)
    .ToDictionary(k => "Name " + k, v => new MyClass("Name " + v, "Second Value " + v));
```

Comment: That's a good solution but unfortunately the values were just place holders. I didn't mean that for what I'm doing they would carry a number at the end. Thanks for the response regardless, it would be useful in other circumstances.